# Login and create username and password program

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a password program that you can login to or make a new user.
I want to make this better, so any help would be appreciated, also any suggestions to make this better would be good

```py
import time  
LOGIN = ("Login", "login", "L", "l", "LOGIN")  
CREATE = ("Create", "create", "C", "c", "CREATE", "Create Account", "Create account", "create Account", "create account", "CREATE ACCOUNT")   
x = 0  
newPass = "X"  
newUser = "X"  

validEntry = {  
    "Liam" : "liampass",  
    "Bob" : "bobpass"  
}  #All current usernames and passwords stored in this dictionary

print("--==Welcome==--")  
time.sleep(1)  
def choice():  
    print("Login or Create Account?")  
    choice = input(":>>>")  
    if choice in LOGIN:  
        login()  
    elif choice in CREATE:  
        create()           #Choice to login or create

def login():  
    print("""  
Please login. Case sensitive.""")  
    time.sleep(0.5)  
    print("Username.")  
    entry = input(":>>>")  
    if entry in validEntry:  
        x = 0  
        while x < 3:  
            print("Input Password.")  
            passentry = input(":>>>")  
            passright = validEntry.get(entry)  #Checks dictionary to find password associated with username entered
            if passentry == passright:  
                print("Successful Login!")     
                x += 5  #Correct password, addition code could be added here
            else:  
                print("""Incorrect password, try again  
                      """)  
                x += 1     #Incorrect password, allows three attempts 
    else:  
        print("Username not recognised!")  
        login()  

def create():  
    print("Please choose a username")  
    newUser = str(input(":>>>"))  
    print("Please choose a password for", newUser)  
    newPass = str(input(":>>>"))  
    global newUser, newPass  #Globalizes both new password and username for entry to dictionary 

choice()  

validEntry[newUser] = newPass #Adds new username and password to dictionary  

choice()  #You can only make one new account then login
```

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code and provide suggestions on how that code can be improved. Unfortunately we can't help you write code that isn't written yet, such as adding a new username and password to a file.

Comment: @pacmaninbw OP rephrased the question since your comment. Looks okay...ish now, I'd say.

Comment: @AlexV VTC retracted

Comment: @pacmaninbw what is a 'VTC'?

Comment: @Yonlif Vote to close. Whenever a question is in violation of the site's rules (as per the [help/on-topic], community members will close the question so it isn't answered by accident. Closed questions should be fixed *before* they're answered to improve the quality and helpfulness of both the question an answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some suggestions, some regarding the code and some regarding the logic of it. Generally this is a nice code.
Let's begin, logical suggestions:

- First of all, the code does not run. `SyntaxError: name 'newUser' is used prior to global declaration`. You should put the `global` keyword before declaring the variables.
- Use the `__main__` function. Usually when writing a good python code you do not write logic outside of functions. This will make your code more readable. You can than put the logic in a `while True` loop and keep accept users forever and not just twice.

Coding suggestions:

- Magic numbers. The number of time you can accept a wrong password is 3, make it a constant: `NUMBER_OF_ERROR = 3`.
- You do not need to declare `x` outside of the `login` function.
- Instead of `x += 5` just use break, it makes much more sense.
- Do not call the login function at the end of login. It creates unnecessary recursion.

That's it.
Good luck and have fun